# Visual studio and VS code are interfering with audio from my browser

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, audio

If I am listening to music or trying to watch a video there is a chance that I will get no sound from it. It takes a little while for it to go away (I normally reload and/or open other videos until it works) but can be rather frustrating because of how often it happens. It only happens when VS or VS code is open and stops as soon as they're closed, it doesn't seem to matter how many or what files I have open. I am using chrome on windows 10. Any idea as to what could be the cause.
Thanks.

Comment: You might try setting all the `Audio Cues: ...` settings to `off` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Leaving this here because I found this question when looking for a solution to my own problem. Maybe it's actually the same issue, but for me sound would be very choppy when scrolling through a file in Visual Studio, or opening a git compare or the like. Doing nothing would make everything fluent again. What helped was changing _Power mode_ under Windows Settings > System > Power & battery to **Best performance**. Sorry, nature, but it drives me mad if my music is continuously getting interrupted.